# Reset password of a User with Root priviliges after disabling Root Access WHM

Tags: ssh, root, whm

Thanks for reading my question.
I have a big issue with SSH on my server; 
I've disabled a month ago "root" access via SSH
Created a new user called "admin", added it to the wheel group and su root priviliges
This way, I will need to login with "admin" user only ...

But, but, the problem is NOW : I forgot the "admin" PASSWORD...
Is there anyway to fix this problem via WHM or SSH... ?

Regards,

Comment: This site is for help writing software. You should consider asking this question on http://serverfault.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change your admin pass through WHM. But I will suggest you please create one test account through WHM and enable shall access for that user, And after that you can add that user in wheel group and login SSH with that user password. After that you can reset the admin pass through root user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've created a new user and logged via SSH ... when I try to change password of admin it says : "Only root user can specify a user name" ... so I used "su " to get root privilges but root can't be used cause I've changed the ssh config file and disabled PermitRootLogin to no ... Please advice

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution:
go to your Google Cloud account on deployment manager click to Opne SSH
follow this steps:
$ sudo passwd

New Password:______________
retype NewPassword :_______________

[image]